# How to use the domain of my old site to my new site?

Tags: domains, dns

the site1.com is a joomla website.. that site is converted into wordpress. I want to have the domain of the joomla site (site1.com) to be the domain name of the wordpress.

Note the two site have different server.

thanks

Comment: @Mike Pennington, i believe you are offending a newbie, show some  professionalism

Comment: @Geewiz: It offends me that you would post **twice** without reading the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @PengOne, I'm sorry. It is the first time I use (post a question) this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you get into DNS manager.  Changing the A entry to whatever your new ip address is will do the trick.

Comment: Great advise, however remember to look before you leap, test it works by editing your local hosts file (/etc/hosts, %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, etc) and putting in the new domain/IP pair.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your domain manager and point the domain name to the new server IP address. If you use something like godaddy it's in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Wordpress ready in the new server.
2. Set the configuration file in Wordpress to point to the `site1.com` domain name.
3. Go to your domain name management system, and update the Nameserver address to your new server address.
4. Wait for the DNS to propogate.
5. Remove your old Joomla site.